# OFFSET and MATCH issue. MATCH value not being recognised as reference within OFFSET formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, offset

I'm trying to find the first instance of "Net" in a range, then using offset to find the value two cells below "net". The MATCH part works fine but when put the MATCH formula into the  OFFSET formula as the reference it is not being recognized as the reference. Instead, 2 is reference when it should be rows, and 0 is rows when it should be cols. Any suggestions?

```
=OFFSET(MATCH("net",1:1)2, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OFFSET()` is used to offset from a cell's reference, not the numerical outcome of `MATCH()`.

Instead try something like:

```
=INDEX(3:3,MATCH("Net",1:1,0))
```

Notice the "0" as the 3rd parameter inside the `MATCH()` function to perform an exact match. Removing this "0" does **not** result in returning the last position of "net". If the rightmost position is what you are after, try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1="Net"),3:3)
```

Or usings, Microsoft365's `XMATCH()`:

```
=INDEX(3:3,XMATCH("net",1:1,0,-1))
```

Comment: What I should have mentioned is it must search from right to left (as there are two or more instances of "net" in the row). Using the MATCH part of my original formula does this but INDEX appears to search from left to right. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @MaximumP, if you found your non-exact `MATCH()` working for you, then just remove the "0" parameter again though it does not really return the position of the last "net". May I ask what version of Excel you are using? I edited the answer with a proper way of finding the rightmost occurence of "net".

Comment: Can't see where the year is displayed but it says Microsoft 365 MSO ( 16.0.13801.20288) 64 bit. Removing to 0 parameter still searches left to right, thus returning the incorrect "net" value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `+2` with match() function to get content of 2 cells below.

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH("Net",A1:A6,0)+2)
```

In case of `OFFSET()` add `+1`

```
=OFFSET(A1,MATCH("Net",A1:A6,0)+1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: The data is spread over Columns and not rows as in your example, the formula is not what @MaximumP is looking for